# How to retrieve a list of nested children from Firebase using query?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying too much to get retrieve from a list of children using Firebase query but failed.There is my code.Every time i get 0 in my logcat which means that datasnapshot.getchildren return nothing.How to fix it?Below i share my database screenshot.

```
 Query queryRef = databaseReference.child("Class").orderByChild("name").equalTo(contactofSA.getName());
    queryRef.getRef().child("Student").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final ArrayList<student> studentListFromServer=new ArrayList<student>();
          if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()==0){
              Log.d("GK","0");
          }
            for(DataSnapshot StudentData:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                student student=new student();
                student=StudentData.getValue(student.class);
                studentListFromServer.add(student);
            }

            studentActivity.studentList=new ArrayList<>();
            studentActivity.studentList=studentListFromServer;
            studentListAdapter.addAll(studentList);
            studentItems.setAdapter(studentListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[I actually want to get this red marked child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baJtK.png)

Comment: its nested too much, but to query it you need to go from top to Student, so child("Class").child(get_key_here).child("Student"). You are not getting the key between Class and student, why do you have a key there anw? just do Class>Student>unique key for every student

Comment: Bro,How to get the Push id i used to push "class" item?i actually cannot get the push id (ex:-KyEqqJ58SC9M2L90tWM) to go to "student".using "getkey" ,every time i get the key "student", not "-KyEqqJ58SC9M2L90tWM".please bro,kindly give me a the complete query please. @peterSmith